# Infinite WHILE LOOP with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following while loop, and it never stops. It ends by printing out 8 forever. Can anybody tell me why?

```
DECLARE @catID int

SELECT TOP(1)
    @catID = categoryid 
FROM 
    [Production].[Categories] 
ORDER BY 
    categoryid

WHILE @catID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID    --do something

    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catID = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue must be that at some point your `SELECT` statement doesn't find any value and doesn't assign anything new to your `@catID` variable and it keeps exactly the same as it was in previous loop. As a result - you never exit your while statement.

Code snippet to explain that:

```
DECLARE @catID INT = 5;

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    CategoryID INT
);

/**
 * Notice that I do not insert into table intentionally,
 * so that following query doesn't assign anything
 * to @catID variable
 */

SELECT TOP (1) @catID = CategoryID
FROM @Test;

SELECT @catID AS [@catID];
```

Result:

```
@catID
-----------
5
```

This query returns 5, and not `NULL` as you would expect.

Assigning value using subquery will either assign an actual value or `NULL` if nothing's found, that means when there's no category higher than `@catID` it will become `NULL` and your query will escape loop.

```
DECLARE @catID INT;

SET @catID = (
    SELECT TOP (1) CategoryID
    FROM Production.Categories
    ORDER BY CategoryID
    );

WHILE @catID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID;

    SET @catID = (
        SELECT TOP (1) CategoryID
        FROM Production.Categories
        WHERE CategoryID > @catID
        ORDER BY CategoryID
        );
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the logical problem with your code:

- The loop breaks when `@catID` becomes `NULL`
- This would require that the first record in the query have `@catID` being `NULL`,
- which in turn would require the `WHERE` clause for that record to be `TRUE`, returning the record
- However, if `@catID` were `NULL`, then the `WHERE` condition would never be true: `WHERE categoryid > @catID`

The reason for this is that comparing the `cateogoryid` against a `NULL` value using inequality will always return `NULL` (unknown), rather than true or false.

**How to fix this:**

You can try adding an additional check to the `WHERE` clause which allows the `NULL` breaking record to be returned:

```
WHILE @catID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID

    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catID = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID OR @catID IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid
END
```

Comment: Hy thanx for your answer. Your code still runs inifnitely. i think because the WHERE is executed before the SELECT

Comment: What is the logic for which the loop should end?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **re-initialize** your variable `@catID` to `NULL` before selecting again - since if there's nothing left to select, no row will be returned and the previous value will remain in `@catID` (and therefore, it never is set to NULL and the `IS NOT NULL` condition is never met).

Try this:

```
WHILE @catID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID    --do something

    SET @catID = NULL   -- re-initilatize to NULL

    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catID = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid
END
```

Comment: Hy thanx for your answer. But its wrong, i think because the WHERE is executed before the SELECT, so categoryis > NULL is never true..

Answer (score 0):

as for why
this will return zero rows every time
you already have top so there will be no categoryid > @catID

@catID is not assigned a value of null
It is not not assigned at all

```
   SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catID = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid
```

fix

```
DECLARE @catID int 
DECLARE @count int = 1 

SELECT TOP(1)
    @catID = categoryid 
FROM 
    [Production].[Categories] 
ORDER BY 
    categoryid

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID    --do something

    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catID = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid

    Select @count = select count(*) FROM [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE categoryid > @catID
END
```

But your logic has more problems. After you get the top 1 you have it.  There are no more top 1 to get.

or

```
DECLARE @catID int
DECLARE @catIDnew int

SELECT TOP(1)
    @catID = categoryid 
FROM 
    [Production].[Categories] 
ORDER BY 
    categoryid

WHILE @catID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @catID    --do something

    @catIDnew = null

    SELECT TOP(1) 
        @catIDnew = categoryid 
    FROM 
        [Production].[Categories] 
    WHERE 
        categoryid > @catID
    ORDER BY 
        categoryid

    @catID =@catIDnew

END
```